# Number of docs without nested docs

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I'm trying to figure out how to do something like this example. Let's say I have 3 documents with the following structure:

```
{
    "name": "test one",
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 1
        }
    ]
}


{
    "name": "test two",
    "images": []
}


{
    "name": "test three",
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to either get a count of documents **WITH** objects in the `images` field (which in this case would be 2), or (less preferably) the count of documents **WITHOUT** objects in the `images` field (in this case, 1). This is for one of the aggregation queries, in case this is not obvious. I've tried about 100 different aggregation types, including this

```
... 
"withoutPhotos": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "images"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "noPhoto": {
      "missing": {
        "field": "images.id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this,

```
... 
"withoutPhotos": {
  "missing": {
    "field": "images"
  }
}
```

and a plenitude of others. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

here's a query to return the results that are missing the images.id field (looks very similar to yours):

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index/test/_search?search_type=count&pretty' -d '
> { "query" :{
> "match_all": { } 
>    },
>    "aggs": {
>     "noPhoto": { "missing": {"field": "images.id"}  }
>   }
> }'
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "noPhoto" : {
      "doc_count" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a query to return the number of instances images.id - not entirely sure if this is what you want (it's returning a field count rather than document count).

```
olly@HomePC:~$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index/test/_search?search_type=count&pretty' -d '
> { "query" :{
> "match_all": { } 
>    },
>    "aggs": {
>  "images_count" : { "value_count" : { "field" : "images.id" } }
>   }
> }'
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "images_count" : {
      "value" : 2
    }
  }
}
```

The other options would be to put something in the query that looks for "images.id" - e.g. a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this approach.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/test/_search?search_type=count&pretty' -d '
 { "query" :{
  "match_all": { } 
     },
    "aggs": {
     "noImage": { "missing": {"field": "images.id"}  }
   }
 }'
```

Result

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "noImage" : {
      "doc_count" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

Here hits.total would be the total number of documents in that index.
aggregations.noImage.doc_count is the number of documents which don't have the image.
Hence the number of documents that have image field would be hits.total - aggregations.noImage.doc_count

1. Documents having image = hits.total - aggregations.noImage.doc_count
2. Documents don't having image = aggregations.noImage.doc_count